# freeze_graph.py under tensorflow/tools output_node_names what should i set？

Tags: tensorflow, graph, model, neural-network, freeze

I just do the test in tensorflow/model in GitHub,and I have trained and got four files, than I freeze the model, and the problem Is coming.
I am supported that
You need to supply the name of a node to `--output_node_names`.

and I have red the `graph.pbtxt`,it is so long ...

the basic format

```
node{
name: "ParseSingleExample/Squeeze_Shape_image/object/bbox/ymin/size"
op: "Const"
  device: "/device:CPU:0"
  attr {
    key: "_output_shapes"
    value {
      list {
        shape {
          dim {
            size: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  and so....

}
```

what should I do ,
thank you

Answer (score 1):

> when defining your graph you can set names of your placeholders / nodes, e.g.

```
# Initialize tensorflow placeholders
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, self.time_steps, self.num_features], name='input_node')
y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, self.num_features], name='output_node')
```

Whereas `y` is the placeholder for your Labels. Consequently your `output_node_name` would be `'output_node'`

Note: If there is no `name` Attribute you need to fall back on the `tf.identity` method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to manually add an identity node with the name you want by using tf.identity.